# Actualizar variable ciclo Matlab

Tags: matlab

Actualmente estoy creando un script en Matlab para generar un archivo con las carcteristicas de una señal. Este es el codigo utilizado:

```
clear;
folder = dir('sonidos');
m = length(folder);

fileW = fopen('caracteristicas.txt','wt');

for i = 3:m
    file = strcat('sonidos/', folder(i).name);
    fprintf('Leyendo Archivo: %s \n', file);
    [y, Fs] = audioread(file);
     max = max(y);
    mean = mean(y);
    min = min(y);
    median = median(y);
    peak2peak = peak2peak(y);
    peak2rms = peak2rms(y);
    rms = rms(y);
    rssq = rssq(y);
    std = std(y);
    var = var(y);
    kurtosis = kurtosis(y);
    power = (norm(y)^2)/length(y);
    fprintf('Caracteristicas: %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
            Fs, max, mean, min, median, peak2peak, peak2rms, rms, rssq, std, var, kurtosis, power);
    fprintf(fileW,'%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
                  Fs, max, mean, min, median, peak2peak, peak2rms, rms, rssq, std, var, kurtosis, power);
end

fclose(fileW);
```

Lo que deseo es leer los archivos de sonido en el directorio 'sonidos', obtener las caracteristicas de la señal y posteriormente escribir en un archivo plano las caracteristicas obtenidas.

Cuando entra al primer ciclo el programa funciona bien, pero en el segundo ciclo me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

¿Alguna idea para solucionar el error? Gracias

Comment: Las variables locales estan sobrescribiendo las funciones de matlab. min1 = min(y)

Comment: En realidad la situación expuesta no se ocasiona cuando sobre-escribes una función sólo una vez, por ejemplo `function y=promedio(x) y = sum(x)/length(x); end` `z=1:10; promedio = promedio(z);` es en la segunda iteración `i=2` que se presenta, y tal como señalaste re-nombrar los variables `_promedio = promedio(z);` soluciona esto.